# Elastic APM Agent KIbana UI Transactions are NA

Tags: elasticsearch, apm

We have newly introduced elastic APM to monitor application performance. After the deployment, we have an issue with Kibana APM UI that doesn't show up any transactions for few services.

[image]

we are having data in the APM indice but doesn't transactions show up in the Kibana APM dashboard   UI we get Avg.response time N/A and Trans.per minute is 0.

APM-Server 7.6.1
Elastic Agent - 1.15.0
ELK Stack - 7.6.1

Please help me on this to identify the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally noticed issue.

application API is returning service name as Bootstrap because.

```
in the Response Headers we are getting bootstrapp {
  "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  "Date": "Fri, 10 Apr 2020 20:01:37 GMT",
  "Server": "Jetty(9.2.13.v20150730)",
  "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
  "X-Application-Context": "bootstrap:31144"
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

Id is not set so it is using default value

The Id can be set like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args).setId("the text that you want to see int the header");
    }
```